# When trying to replace two character with one the application crashes. It works fine with one character replacement

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application and I struggle with replacing two characters with one.
It works when replacing only one character but fails when replacing two characters with one at the same time. 
I found that the application can replace two character with two new character properly.

Could you please help me point out what the issue is and how I could potentially fix my code?

```
tt = new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                et.setSelection(s.length());            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                et.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
                String tvalue = et.getText().toString();
                tvalue = tvalue.replaceAll("k", "1");;
                tvalue = tvalue.replaceAll("1h", "2");
    //THE first line replaces "k" with "1" WORKS FINE BUT THE second line for replacing "1h" with "2" DOES NOT. IT CRASHES. I found that it is possible to replace "1h" with "2 "(two followed by space)!
      et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
            }
        };
        et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
    }
setSelection(s.length());
```

Thanks in advance. This is my first question on this site.

**Below is the logcat**

```
02-02 09:39:27.674      838-838/in.healthy100.gujjuwriter E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (10 ... 10) ends beyond length 9
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
            at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
            at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
            at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:94)
            at in.healthy100.gujjuwriter.MyActivity$1.onTextChanged(MyActivity.java:270)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
            at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
            at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9183)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
            at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
            at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:223)
            at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:136)
            at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5532)
            at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5343)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7665)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1408)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1505)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2418)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1962)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3826)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3558)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2010)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1704)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1695)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1987)
            at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.j
02-02 09:39:27.674      838-838/in.healthy100.gujjuwriter D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that is causing the error:

```
setSelection(s.length());
```

You are attempting to set the cursor to the end of the string, using the length of the original string. When you run this code:

```
tvalue = tvalue.replaceAll("k", "1");
```

the length of the string does not change, so using the original length is ok. However, when you run this code:

```
tvalue = tvalue.replaceAll("1h", "2");
```

the length of the string will be reduced because you are replacing 2 characters with 1 character. Therefore calling setSelection() with the length of the original string will cause an out of bounds error, because you are trying to move the cursor past the end of the string.

The solution is to call setSelection() using the length of the new string after the replacements have been done:

```
setSelection(tvalue.length());
```